# Sum over all dates but keep only last date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, max, aggregate-functions

In SQL Server, I would like to obtain the sum of the AMOUNT grouped by the BOOKING ID, but also the max date of the DEPARTURE DATE per BOOKING ID as an extra column.

```
 BOOKING ID | DEPARTURE DATE | AMOUNT
       1       2013-04-12        100
       1       2013-04-14        120
       1       2013-04-9          90
       2       2013-04-14        100
       2       2013-04-18        150
       3       2013-04-12        100
```

Desired result:

```
BOOKING ID  |   MAX DATE   | AMOUNT
       1       2013-04-14      310
       2       2013-04-18      250
       3       2013-04-12      100
```

Seems like an easy problem, but with my limited SQL Server knowledge I can only think of temporary tables as a solution.

My attempt:

```
SELECT
[BOOKING ID]
,MAX([DEPARTURE DATE])
,SUM(AMOUNT)
from table
GROUP BY BOOKING ID, [DEPARTURE DATE]
```

Any simple solutions for this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with `MAX` and `SUM`? What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried summing over AMOUNT and group by BOOKING ID and DATE, but then it returns the sum per DATE. I also tried summing over AMOUNT of max(DATE), but then it doesn't sum over the other dates.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except_ those who are arguments to set functions. Will be `GROUP BY [BOOKING ID]` here.

Comment: Ouch, this was a very stupid question indeed. Should I delete the question or keep it for other beginners as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use aggregation:

```
select booking_id, max(depature_date) as max_date, sum(amount) as amount
from mytable
group by booking_id
```